# How to block calls to print?

Tags: python, printing, pygame

Is there a way to stop a function from calling `print`?

---

I am using the [`pygame.joystick`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) module for a game I am working on.

I created a `pygame.joystick.Joystick` object and in the actual loop of the game call its member function `get_button` to check for user input. The function does everything I need it to do, but the problem is that it also calls `print`, which slows down the game considerably.

Can I *block* this call to `print`?

Comment: This ought to be considered a bug in the module in question (perhaps long since fixed, of course).  Libraries have no business writing to the standard streams except on request.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Python lets you overwrite standard output (stdout) with any file object.  This should work cross platform and write to the null device.

```
import sys, os

# Disable
def blockPrint():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

# Restore
def enablePrint():
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


print 'This will print'

blockPrint()
print "This won't"

enablePrint()
print "This will too"
```

If you don't want that one function to print, call `blockPrint()` before it, and `enablePrint()` when you want it to continue.  If you want to disable *all* printing, start blocking at the top of the file.

Comment: This seems to have permanently blocked print for me. enablePrint does not restore it

Comment: This solution won't restore properly printing to the Jupyter cells

Comment: I guess the argument to print is still evaluated, so it will take longer than the script with all print lines manually commented out?

Comment: for Jupyter you can monkey-patch-save the original stdout in `sys` as `sys._jupyter_stdout = sys.stdout` in `blockPrint` and restore to it in `enablePrint`

Comment: This post is out of date (uses python 2 style prints).  Also, using a context manager as laid out in another answer is safer.

Answer (score 162):

### Use `with`

Based on @FakeRainBrigand solution I'm suggesting a safer solution:

```py
import os, sys

class HiddenPrints:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
with HiddenPrints():
    print("This will not be printed")

print("This will be printed as before")
```

This is much safer because you can not forget to re-enable stdout, which is especially critical when handling exceptions.

### Bad practice: Without `with`

The following example uses enable/disable prints functions that were suggested in previous answer.

Imagine that there is a code that may raise an exception. We had to use `finally` statement in order to enable prints in any case.

```
try:
    disable_prints()
    something_throwing()
    enable_prints() # This will not help in case of exception
except ValueError as err:
    handle_error(err)
finally:
    enable_prints() # That's where it needs to go.
```

If you forgot the `finally` clause, none of your `print` calls would print anything anymore.

**It is safer to use the `with` statement, which makes sure that prints will be reenabled.**

Note: It is not safe to use `sys.stdout = None`, because someone could call methods like `sys.stdout.write()`

Comment: Very good solution! I just wrote the same thing and then found you already answered that way :D

I'll add a bit of information about why this is a better way to do it.

Comment: Noobie question here: Would it be important to close() devnull after exiting the class?

Comment: @Wadsworth, I don't know the answer. I guess devnull's properties do not require it to be closed properly. But rumors say that you should always close open handlers to release resources. CPython as I know should close devnull itself as far as garbage collector get it.

Comment: I was getting `ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/dev/null' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>` when using this code, solved it by setting sys.stdout = None instead of open(os.devnull,'w')

Comment: @WellDone2094, thanks. I've added `sys.stdout.close()` to the exit method. This should help. Note that `sys.stdout = None` may cause an error, because someone may call stdout's methods like `sys.stdout.write()`.

Comment: My function processes successfully if I don't use 
with HiddenPrints(). When I use it throws an error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u017c' in position 204: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: @SyedMdIsmail I think you should check what line causes error exactly. You may have some logger attached or, who knows, maybe you have replaced original print function with another implementation.

Comment: This is extremely useful for debugging. Why didn't I see this before?

Answer (score 78):

As @Alexander Chzhen suggested, using a context manager would be safer than calling a pair of state-changing functions.

However, you don't need to reimplement the context manager - it's already in the standard library. You can redirect `stdout` (the file object that `print` uses) with [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout), and also `stderr` with [`contextlib.redirect_stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr).

```
import os
import contextlib

with open(os.devnull, "w") as f, contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
    print("This won't be printed.")
```

You can encapsulate this logic by defining your own wrapper context manager:

```
import os
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def suppress_print():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as f, contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        yield


print("This will be printed")
with suppress_print():
    print("This will not")
print("Printing works outside the with-statement")
```

Comment: Does not work for me! Function is still printing...

Comment: @PascalIv What exactly did you try? Still works for me in Python 3.9 on Linux.

Comment: I realized it's because I am using Colab. But I got it to work with

`from IPython.utils import io
with io.capture_output() as captured:
    print("I will not be printed.")`

Comment: for me, this used to work in Python 3.7, but moving to 3.9 no longer works

Comment: @Guillaume works for me on Python 3.10.4 on Linux. It also worked for me on Python 3.9 last time someone raised an issue with it, as evident in a previous comment. You're going to need to provide more context.

Comment: I have created a question for it, because maybe it is related to AWS Lambda then? on my Mac with Python 3.9, simply doing `logger.removeHandler(sys.stdout)` is enough, but somehow the Lambda/CloudWatch still prints everything!

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389347/disable-logging-on-aws-lambda-python-3-9/72393167

Comment: This does not work in a multithreaded application.

Comment: @Burak The `contextlib` documentation advises that this method may not be suitable for multithreaded applications, but without further information, I cannot provide help.

Comment: Is there a way to encapsulate this so the implementation in code is cleaner?  ex: `with supressprint()` above the offending function call, but it executes the contextlib method above?

Comment: @turbonate I've updated the answer to show how you can encapsulate it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to block print calls made by a particular function, there is a neater solution using decorators. Define the following decorator:

```
# decorater used to block function printing to the console
def blockPrinting(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # block all printing to the console
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        # call the method in question
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # enable all printing to the console
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        # pass the return value of the method back
        return value

    return func_wrapper
```

Then just place `@blockPrinting` before any function. For example:

```
# This will print
def helloWorld():
    print("Hello World!")
helloWorld()

# This will not print
@blockPrinting
def helloWorld2():
    print("Hello World!")
helloWorld2()
```

For `Jupyter Notebooks` you may need to replace the `func_wrapper` code with:

```
from IPython.utils.io import capture_output

def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    with capture_output():
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
    return value
```

Comment: Used this in a jupyter notebook - printing has been permanently disabled i.e. even helloWorld() wouldn't print anything if I run it for the second time

Comment: I've updated the answer with a code snippet which will work with Jupyter Notebooks

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Jupyter Notebook or Colab use this:

```
from IPython.utils import io

with io.capture_output() as captured:
    print("I will not be printed.")
```

Comment: This does work well with functions(that print stuff) defined in the notebook itself. However, if I use an api call (to [Microsoft Form recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-formrecognizer/azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysisclient?view=azure-python#azure-ai-formrecognizer-documentanalysisclient-begin-analyze-document)) , it starts printing the api request details anyways.  Do you know why this would happen? Is there something that the api is overriding?

Answer (score 3):

A completely different approach would be redirecting at the command line.  If you're on Windows, this means a batch script.  On Linux, bash.

```
/full/path/to/my/game/game.py > /dev/null
C:\Full\Path\To\My\Game.exe > nul
```

Unless you're dealing with multiple processes, this *should* work.  For Windows users this could be the shortcuts you're creating (start menu / desktop).

Answer (score 3):

You can do a simple redirection, this seems a lot safer than messing with stdout, and doesn't pull in any additional libraries.

```
enable_print  = print
disable_print = lambda *x, **y: None

print = disable_print
function_that_has_print_in_it(1)  # nothing is printed

print = enable_print
function_that_has_print_in_it(2)  # printing works again!
```

Note: this only works to disable the print() function, and would not disable all output if you're making calls to something else that is producing output. For instance if you were calling a C library that was producing it's own output to stdout, or if you were using intput().

Comment: The example I listed does work, but if you have an example where you have tried something similar and it did not work for you, you will have to be more explicit about what you tried and what changes you made. What version of Python were you using?

Comment: I like the idea, but it only worked for me if I dealt with `__builtins__.print` specifically.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, and I did not come to another solution but to redirect the output of the program (I don't know exactly whether the spamming happens on stdout or stderr) to `/dev/null` nirvana.

Indeed, it's open source, but I wasn't passionate enough to dive into the `pygame` sources - and the build process - to somehow stop the debug spam.

**EDIT :**

The [`pygame.joystick` module](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.zip) has calls to `printf` in all functions that return the actual values to Python:

```
printf("SDL_JoystickGetButton value:%d:\n", value);
```

Unfortunately you would need to comment these out and recompile the whole thing. Maybe the provided `setup.py` would make this easier than I thought. You could try this...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not, especially that majority of PyGame is written in C.

But if this function calls print, then it's PyGame bug, and you should just report it.

Answer (score 1):

The module I used printed to `stderr`. So the solution in that case would be:

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"stop a function from calling print"
# import builtins
# import __builtin__ # python2, not test
printenabled = False
def decorator(func):
    def new_func(*args,**kwargs):
        if printenabled:
            func("print:",*args,**kwargs)
    return new_func
print = decorator(print) # current file
# builtins.print = decorator(builtins.print)  # all files
# __builtin__.print = decorator(__builtin__.print) # python2

import sys
import xxxxx
def main():
    global printenabled
    printenabled = True
    print("1 True");
    printenabled = False
    print("2 False");
    printenabled = True
    print("3 True");
    printenabled = False
    print("4 False");
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())

#output
print: 1 True
print: 3 True
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27622201

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Change value of file object of print() function. By default it's `sys.stdout`, instead we can write to null device by `open(os.devnull, 'w')`

```
import os, sys

mode = 'debug' #'prod'

if mode == 'debug':
    fileobj = sys.stdout
else:
    fileobj = open(os.devnull,'w')

print('Hello Stackoverflow', file = fileobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Alexander Chzhen solution, I present here the way to apply it on a function with an option to suppress printing or not.

```
    import os, sys
    class SuppressPrints:
        #different from Alexander`s answer
        def __init__(self, suppress=True):
            self.suppress = suppress

        def __enter__(self):
            if self.suppress:
                self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
                sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            if self.suppress:
                sys.stdout.close()
                sys.stdout = self._original_stdout
    #implementation
    def foo(suppress=True):
        with SuppressPrints(suppress):
            print("It will be printed, or not")

    foo(True)  #it will not be printed
    foo(False) #it will be printed
```

I hope I can add my solution below answer of Alexander as a comment, but I don`t have enough (50) reputations to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable/disable print with a variable, you could call an auxiliary function instead print, something like printe(the name is just for convenience)

```
def printe(*what_to_print):
if prints_enable:
    string = ""
    for items in what_to_print:
        string += str(items) + " "
    print(string)
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a new Print function where you enable print first. print your output next. And then disable print again.

```
def Print (*output):
   enablePrint()
   print (output)
   disablePrint()
```

with one of the above "safe" enable / disable pair of function

Comment: what's "enablePrint" and "disablePrint"?

Comment: I did not want to repeat the codings again. So you you could choose any of the above mentioned stdout redirection functionds, especially the "safe" one by Alexander C, with the "with" option.