# How to enable print() after disabling it?

Tags: python, printing

I have the exact same question as [Python + Disabled print output, and can't get it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464444/python-disabled-print-output-and-cant-get-it-back). I used the following code to suppress printing:

```
# Disable
def blockPrint():
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

# Restore
def enablePrint():
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

The top solution to this question was to store the old `stdin` by the following line, but I have already disabled printing. How can I restore this?

```
sys.__stdout__ = sys.stdout
```

Comment: Can't you just store it before disabling it?

Comment: My problem is that I only saw this post after disabling it.

Comment: The "disabling" only lasts during the current program run. If you close your program and restart it, everything will be restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments above:

- Disabling it only lasts during the program run. Closing and restarting it will fix it.
- To disable and restore in the same program run, store sys.stdin in a temporary variable before disabling it, like this:

```py
temp_stdout = None

# Disable
def blockPrint():
    global temp_stdout
    temp_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

# Restore
def enablePrint():
    global temp_stdout
    sys.stdout = temp_stdout
```