# How to suppress automatically generated output from a Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I want to suppress auto generated output from this line of code:

```
cp = client.fetch_market_depth(a)["Data"][0]['LastTradedPrice']
```

Here [`client.fetch_market_depth()`](https://github.com/5paisa/py5paisa/blob/2b3403b305062fd98a27fde8b67336778929b08e/py5paisa/py5paisa.py#L257) is part of [coding API](https://github.com/5paisa/py5paisa) developed by 5paisa.
It's using [`log_response`](https://github.com/5paisa/py5paisa/blob/3bb8af85d4015d1d2620fbfc443127998912bc54/py5paisa/logging.py) to output debug messages.

It outputs "current time | Success"

After googling and using code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464444/python-disabled-print-output-and-cant-get-it-back) of Stack Overflow, I am using following code. Still it is unable to suppress the output. What option I have now? I use Python 3.

After I receive the suggestion in comment, I edited the code and redirected output from stderr too. Still it's printing same output.

```
class HiddenPrints:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        self._original_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout
        sys.stderr = self._original_stderr

SC1 = 20374
a=[{"Exchange":"N","ExchangeType":"C","ScripCode":SC1},]
with HiddenPrints():
    cp = client.fetch_market_depth(a)["Data"][0]['LastTradedPrice']
```

Comment: Maybe overload the print method (as a guess...)?

Comment: Have you tried the IPython magic `%%capture`? Or check if the library you are using has some flags you can set.

Comment: Is any of the output being written to stderr?  If so, then you may need to redirect that as well.

Comment: @TomKarzes : Tried, did not work. Kindly check the edit.

Comment: We have no idea what `fetch_market_depth` does or how it generates its output.

Comment: @triplee : It is part of trading api developed by 5paisa. here is the link : https://github.com/5paisa/py5paisa

Comment: The code in https://github.com/5paisa/py5paisa/blob/2b3403b305062fd98a27fde8b67336778929b08e/py5paisa/py5paisa.py#L257 ends up calling https://github.com/5paisa/py5paisa/blob/3bb8af85d4015d1d2620fbfc443127998912bc54/py5paisa/logging.py which uses the Python `logging` module, but then we'd need to see how you have configured that.

Comment: @tripleee It's using the `loguru` module not `logging`.

Comment: Looks like that the problem is that the py5paisa's logging module gets the reference to the real `sys.stdout` before `HiddenPrints` replaces it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the problem is that [the py5paisa's logging module gets the reference to the real `sys.stdout`](https://github.com/5paisa/py5paisa/blob/v0.4.8-pre-alpha/py5paisa/logging.py#L11) before `HiddenPrints` replaces it.

You need to disable the logger by importing it and calling `logger.disable("")`. And after exiting the context, enable it with `logger.enable("")`.

If you also want to ignore any exceptions, you need to return `True` on exit.

```
class HiddenPrints:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        self._original_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")
        from loguru import logger
        logger.disable("") #disable the logger

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout
        sys.stderr = self._original_stderr
        from loguru import logger
        logger.enable("") #enable the logger
        return True #optionally also ignore exceptions
```