# Python - query over list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that contain a float, and two custom objects:

```
ExampleList = [(10.5, Obj1, Obj2), (11.5, Obj1, Obj2), (14., Obj1, Obj2)]
```

I then have a line of code that appends tuples to that:

```
newTuple = (15,Obj1, Obj2)    
ExampleList.append(newTuple)
```

I am trying to figure out a clean way to add the following kind of line:

If newTuple[0] (the float number) is > than any of the 2nd largest tuple float numbers, append it.  Otherwise no.   Any idea how to do that element-wise boolean on a tuple list?

EDIT - sorry, I meant to add the 2nd largest part.

Thanks- KC

Comment: is your list sorted according to the numbers? And 2nd largest means that `(13,xx)` qualifies, but `(11,xx)` doesn't, right?

Comment: What is your code to find the second largest element of `ExampleList`?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. Did you want to add newTuple, if newTuple[0] is larger than any of the existing counterparts in ExampleList?

Comment: `sorted(ExampleList)[-2][0]` represents the second largest

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - yes, its sorted according to the numbers.  I'm running a large loop that is meant to only record the top 5 'results' (aka the float above)

Comment: @xtrom0rt - yes, except if its larger than the 2ND largest counterparts in that list

Comment: @keynesiancross so your list becomes unsorted as soon as you insert the new element. Wouldn't you need a sorted insert instead of append in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the cleanest way to do it (that I am aware of):

```
secondLargest = sorted(ExampleList)[-2][0]
if (newTuple[0] > secondLargest):
    ExampleList.append(newTuple)
```

Although If you're looking for efficiency, look at @Jean-François Fabre 's answer

Comment: thanks but the efficiency of my method  is yet to be proven. Your method is OK. It allocates more memory, but if the `sort` operation is faster, maybe it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

`max` is ruled out here, since we need the 2nd best value. `sort` would work but it allocates the full sorted list in return, only to discard most of the values.

A nice way of getting the 2nd largest float is to use `heapq.nlargest` in a generator comprehension (better check that input list has at least 2 elements in the general case, though)

```
import heapq

Obj1 = object()
Obj2 = object()

sampleList = [(10.5, Obj1, Obj2), (11.5, Obj1, Obj2), (14., Obj1, Obj2)]

second_largest = heapq.nlargest(2,(x[0] for x in sampleList))[-1]  # [14.0, 11.5]

newTuple = (15,Obj1, Obj2)

if newTuple[0]>second_largest:
    sampleList.append(newTuple)
```

Comment: I like the solution, but I think that's a bit complicated for a small personal program

Comment: Heap will take nlogn in construction which is same as any efficient sort such as quicksort.

Comment: You can use `heapq._heapify_max(sampleList)` to have a heap that is max to min.

Comment: why the nasty `_` before the name? Means it's not recommended to use it internally right?

Comment: @hashcode55 `heap` doesn't return the full list, so it's more efficient memory-wise. Not sure about the overall speed. If one is coded in C and the other is pure python, the C version is probably faster.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hmm, I think its hard to speculate but anyways your method is obviously better in a long run when the user wants to insert multiple tuples based on the same condition. (+1)

Comment: @hashcode55 thanks. Also if the list is big, it may be nice not to allocate a big sorted list to discard most of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is already sorted, I would look at the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module to find the sorted insertion point. Then just calculate if that insertion meets the criteria.

Example:

```
import bisect

Obj1='o1'
Obj2='o2'
sample=[(10.5, Obj1, Obj2), (11.5, Obj1, Obj2), (14., Obj1, Obj2)] # needs to be sorted

newTuple = (13,Obj1, Obj2)

def my_insert(li, t):
    ip=bisect.bisect_left(li, newTuple)
    if len(li)-ip<2:
        li.insert(ip, t)
    else:
        print t, 'not inserted'
```

Testing:

```
>>> my_insert(sample, newTuple); print sample
[(10.5, 'o1', 'o2'), (11.5, 'o1', 'o2'), (13, 'o1', 'o2'), (14.0, 'o1', 'o2')]
>>> my_insert(sample, newTuple); print sample
(13, 'o1', 'o2') not inserted
[(10.5, 'o1', 'o2'), (11.5, 'o1', 'o2'), (13, 'o1', 'o2'), (14.0, 'o1', 'o2')]
```