# How can I hide 'pydub' output information?

Tags: python, hide, silent, pydub

My Code

```
from pydub import generators
from pydub.playback import play

play(generators.Sine(440).to_audio_segment(duration=1500))
```

In the console output:

```
Input #0, wav, from '/var/folders/_7/0q83l2vn4zjd7zgqpy3v97840000gn/T/tmphlm6i9s_.wav':
Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 705 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution yet, but I found besides "pydub" three alternatives. The last one is without output text. (Number-4)

```
import time
from gtts import gTTS
tts = gTTS('Test', lang='en')
tts.save('Test.mp3')

#=================1
print("1")
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("Test.mp3") 
mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(1)

#=================2
print("2")
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
path_to_file = r"Test.mp3"
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path_to_file)
play(song)
time.sleep(1)

#=================3
print("3")
import os
os.system("mpg321 -q Test.mp3")
time.sleep(1)

#=================4
print("4")
from mpyg321.mpyg321 import MPyg321Player
player = MPyg321Player()
player.play_song("Test.mp3")
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find none of the answers mentioned above work.

I finally managed to hide the pydub playback output by using a subprocess.

If you are interested, I implemented at:

https://github.com/eliranwong/UniqueBible/blob/main/util/RemoteCliMainWindow.py#L287

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33961695)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having a problem with my computer, so I'm not able to check this, but this should work:

```
from pydub import generators
from pydub.playback import play
import subprocess, sys

play(generators.Sine(440).to_audio_segment(duration=1500))
if sys.platform in ('linux', 'osx'):
    subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)
elif sys.platform in ('nt', 'dos', 'ce'):
    subprocess.call('cls', shell=True)
else:
    pass
```

This is kind-of a 'hack' in the code that just clears console every time an output is sent.
Something like this may work, but again, I haven't been able to test it:

```
import contextlib
import io

from pydub import generators
from pydub.playback import play

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()):
    play(generators.Sine(440).to_audio_segment(duration=1500))
```

Comment: I tried it before but doesn't work:/ Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work, if anything: you can switch away from pydub. Pydub should give it an option to hide the data. Hope everything works out!

Comment: Comment from GreyAlien502-  If you install simpleaudio (e.g. run pip install simpleaudio),
it should play audio without emitting any text.

N.B. This output is coming from ffplay, which is a used because simpleaudio is not installed.
We don't currently have any way to suppress output from ffplay.
We would need to pass the arguments -loglevel -8 to the ffplay call.
Arguably, this should be the default.

Answer (score 0):

See the request discussion on github: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/247 (I think it's still to do). But following annaproxy you can modify _play_with_ffplay in pydub.playback to redirect stdout and stderr to devnull.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pydub
import pydub.generators
from os import environ
environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = '1'
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
sine = pydub.generators.Sine(440).to_audio_segment(duration=1500).export()
c = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load(sine)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    c.tick(10)
```

[How to disable welcome message when importing pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51464455/how-to-disable-welcome-message-when-importing-pygame)