# Logging module weirdness, wrong display of log message?

Tags: python, python-logging

Here is a small example of something I find very weird about the `logging` module:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

#
# making a hierarchy like this:
#     root
#       |- session
#             |-session.foo
#
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
session_logger = logging.getLogger("session")
foo_logger = logging.getLogger("session.foo")
#
# root_logger and session_logger effective log levels
# are set to 30 (= WARNING)
#
foo_logger.debug("WA") #nothing is printed, so far so good
#
# and now enters the problem...
#
foo_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
foo_logger.debug("HELLO") #HELLO log message is printed!!!
```

I do not get why the 'HELLO' log message is printed, to my understanding
since there is no handler attached to logger `foo_logger` the log message should
bubble up, and effectively be stopped by higher level logger (`session`),
since its level is set to `WARNING` (by default).

It seems like setting the level on `foo_logger` gives it rights to display
through the handler but it is very unclear to me.

Can someone explain to me why the message is printed ?
And what should I do to have the logger hierarchy as I would like ?

Comment: this may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/suppress-calls-to-print-python#8391735

Comment: @DaduKhan sorry but it does not help, since the link you provide is not related to Python logging. My problem is not with print, it is with the fact I can't understand how loggers hierarchy and rules to display or not messages are applied

Comment: `foo_logger` had inherited its logging level from its parent, then you overrode that level.

Comment: @Eqomatic can you elaborate? `foo_logger` has no handler. `.propagate` is set to `True` so I would have expected the log message to bubble up to `session` logger. And the message to not be displayed...

Comment: `foo_logger` also inherited the handler from its parent since `.propogate` is set to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both loggers AND handlers have a `level` setting, and the default level for handlers is `0`. You'd need to set the level of the parent handler - in your case `root_logger.handlers[0]` above `logging.DEBUG` to filter out the `debug()` calls on `foo_logger`:

```
root_logger.handlers[0].level = logging.WARN
foo_logger.debug("peekaboo") # should not be printed
```

Note that `logging.basicConfig()` only does a very simplistic config - it's mostly meant as a way to get started with logging, for any serious configuration you want `dictConfig` instead, which let you specify the handlers, formatters, levels etc as you see fit. Also note that a logger actually has a list of handlers (not a single one) and that multiple loggers can use the same handler, so who logs what (and where) depends on the combination of loggers AND handlers levels (and on the logger's `propagate` option too).

As a practical example, on my current (django) project we have (amongst others) a "console" handler (logs to stdout, which gunicorn redirects to it's own log file) whose level is set to INFO and a "notify" handler (sends emails notifications) with level set to WARN, so that some of our loggers (those for the most sensitive parts) will send INFO and above messages to gunicorn's logs *and* send WARN messages and above as notification emails too.