# How to use a with statement to disable printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I want to use something like this:

```py
print('Hello')
with dont_print():
    print('some other text')
    print('more text')

print('World')
```

The output should be:

```
Hello
World
```

So everything inside the `dont_print` won't get printed.
How can I get a function like this?

Comment: Have you seen the context manager [`redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite your standard output to some file object. Here is your modified version.

```
import sys, os

# Disable
def blockPrint():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

# Restore
def enablePrint():
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


print('Hello')

blockPrint()
print('some other text')
print('more text')

enablePrint()
print('World')
```

More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391735/11548219)

Answer (score 2):

```
from unittest.mock import patch

print('Hello')
with patch('builtins.print'):
    print('some other text')
    print('more text')

print('World')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) as context manager to redirect stdout to nothingness with [`os.devnull`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.devnull):

```py
import os
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

print('Hello')
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('some other text')
        print('more text')
print('World')
```