# How to disable print "Loading configuration... done." in Sumo/Traci

Tags: python, sumo

I'm using traci, and everytime I call `traci.start` it prints `"Loading configuration... done."`. Its really annoying because I am connecting to a lot at once and overtime. I can't seem to find where this print originates. And attempting to disable prints on this `traci.start` call using something such as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/suppress-calls-to-print-python) does not work. I think because a sumo server is created which is connected to and this print comes from the code for this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to discard the complete stdout you can do the following:

```
import subprocess
import sumolib
import traci

PORT = sumolib.miscutils.getFreeSocketPort()
sumoProc = subprocess.Popen(["sumo", "-c", "sumo.sumocfg", "--remote-port", str(PORT)],
                            stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"))
traci.init(PORT)
```

This won't work with libsumo though.