# Any way to suppress output from print calls?

Tags: python, printing

I'm looking for a function that would silence any prints, so for example this line would do nothing:

```
silence(print('hello'))
```

Comment: Typing `#` is easier than typing `silence( )`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/suppress-calls-to-print-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot silence the print because `print` is executed before `silence`:

```
silence(print('hello'))
```

On the other hand, you could do this:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def silence():
    sys.stdout, old = io.StringIO(), sys.stdout
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old

with silence():
    print('hello')
```

All the prints are redirected to an `io.StringIO` object while in the `silence()` context.
You may also choose to do something with the collected prints at the end of the context.

Comment: Good answer, although I would suggest redirecting the output to [`os.devnull`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.devnull) which would simply throw it away an not incur the overhead of storing it in memory.

Comment: @martineau I agree. If the data is not needed, it is better to just throw it away immediately.