# hide undesired output after executing a python program

Tags: python

I have got the answer for "how, inside a python script can I install packages using pip?" which is;

```
from pip._internal import main as pipmain

pipmain(['install', 'package-name'])
```

For backwards compatibility you can use:

```
try:
   from pip import main as pipmain
except ImportError:
   from pip._internal import main as pipmain
```

But if I run it,I get some output showing download information and progress.
Is there any way to not get that(Make the code to just do its business behind the curtain)?

I tried a suggested answer(Below), but it doesnt seem to work.

```
import sys,os
def blockPrint():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
def enablePrint():
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
blockPrint()    
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain
pipmain(['install', 'numpy'])
enablePrint()
print("hello")
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried a few of the solutions but it doesn't seem to work.I'm new to python so I hope you are kind enough to give specific,to the point answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/how-to-block-calls-to-print

Comment: @KrkRamaKrishna I tried but it still shows details of installation.Ive edited the question including that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't if this is what you what, but you can hide the console window by renaming your `.py` file to a `.pyw` file.