# How do I suppress the output from log step while running jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

On [this](https://calmcode.io/pandas-pipe/logs.html) page, there is this log_step function which is being used to record what each step in a pandas pipeline is doing. The exact function is:

```
from functools import wraps
import datetime as dt

def log_step(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        tic = dt.datetime.now()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        time_taken = str(dt.datetime.now() - tic)
        print(f"just ran step {func.__name__} shape={result.shape} took {time_taken}s")
        return result
    return wrapper
```

and it is used in the following fashion:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://calmcode.io/datasets/bigmac.csv')

@log_step
def start_pipeline(dataf):
    return dataf.copy()

@log_step
def set_dtypes(dataf):
    return (dataf
            .assign(date=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['date']))
            .sort_values(['currency_code', 'date']))
```

My question is: how do I keep the @log_step in front of my functions and be able to use them at will, while setting the results of @log_step by default, to not be outputed when I run my Jupyter notebook? I suspect the answer comes down to something more general about using decorators but I don't really know what to look for. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you comment the print that you have in your wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed remove the `print` statement or, if you want to not alter the decorating function, you can as well redirect the `sys` to avoid seeing the prints, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391735/2456624).