# Does blocking printing to console in a thread block it for the whole application? [Python]

Tags: python, printing, stdout

In an application that I'm writing the user can provide a class which will then be trial runned in a thread to see if it throws any exceptions.

However, I want to suppress any printing by that class in that thread. I know how to do this based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/how-to-block-calls-to-print), but my question is if this will block the printing for the whole application? So when this thread is running can other threads still print to the console?

EDIT:
Adding example code from that solutions answer for your convenience:

```
import os, sys

class HiddenPrints:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout

with HiddenPrints():
    print("This will not be printed")

print("This will be printed as before")
```

Comment: Think about it: If you redirect standard output to null (does not matter from which thread), how shall other threads still be able to print to the standard output?

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to confirm this. For beginners it might not be so obvious. I would have asked this as a comment in the referenced solution, but I did not have enough reputation do add comments there.

Answer (score 1):

So as @Markus Safar as pointed out then no, other threads will no be able to print to console as well.