# try except block prints 'hello'

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

I have a perculiar problem.

I'm using the  extract_msg package to analyse a bunch of .msg files.
The package results in an NotImplementedError error when the .msg file contains attachtments.
I'm using a try-except block to catch this error, but for some weird reason its prints "hello" for every error it finds. Nowhere in my code I wrote it to print "hello" so I'm a bit baffled here.

Has anyone seen this before? And how can I avoid this strange thing from happening?

```
#f-variabele 
f = glob.glob(r'D:\AA Brenda\Python\DVS_lang\*\*.msg', recursive=True) 
  
instead of this please do like this and try again  

f = glob.glob(r'D:/AA Brenda/Python/DVS_lang/**/*.msg', recursive=True)
```

```
#loop over folders
paths =[]
senders = []
recipients = []
dates = []
subjects = []
body = []


#append data to lists:
for filename in f:
    try:
        msg = extract_msg.Message(filename)
        paths.append(filename)
        senders.append(msg.sender)
        recipients.append(msg.to)
        dates.append(msg.date)
        subjects.append(msg.subject)
        body.append(msg.body)
    except NotImplementedError:   #"NotImplementedError: Current version of ExtractMsg.py does not 
                                  #support extraction of containers that are not embeded msg files."
        print("")
```

Comment: See this page [I print hello](https://github.com/TeamMsgExtractor/msg-extractor/search?q=hello)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in their library:

https://github.com/TeamMsgExtractor/msg-extractor/blob/master/extract_msg/msg.py#L644

If that really bothers you, you can use the following:
[How to block calls to print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/how-to-block-calls-to-print)

Comment: Yes, and not talking about the fact that you can remove the `print("Hello")` from the library itself (on your local device) is funny.

Comment: Interessting, I hadnt considered that it would be in the library itself. Thanks for pointing that out.