# Speech Recognition module is giving a dictionary as well as a list. Any solutions?

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

[I tried to run the code. It worked very well but leaving a dictionary after being executed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cti3J.png)

[This is the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5lNS.png)
[Code for the wishMe function which is executed at the starting of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1We17.png)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It seems you make use of the package [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/).

On line 54 of `main.py` you call `r.recognize_google()`. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/3f4162faed237845d4dcb0cc01130fd33e715da4/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L917) of this method, on line 917 and 918 it shows that the authors of the package print the results when the method is called.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to suppress print statements in imported code. If it really bothers you, you can modify stdout like they suggest in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/how-to-block-calls-to-print) thread. Or you can fork the repository and change the source code so results only print when you want to.