# determine availability (and price?) of 50k domains

Tags: python, linux, dns, whois

I have a list of 50k possible domain names. I'd like to find out which ones are available and if possible how much they cost.  the list looks like this

```
presumptuous.ly
principaliti.es
procrastinat.es
productivene.ss
professional.ly
profession.ally
professorshi.ps
prognosticat.es
prohibitioni.st
```

I've tried whois but that runs way too slow to complete in the next 100 years.

```
def check_domain(domain):
try:
    # Get the WHOIS information for the domain
    w = whois.whois(domain)
    if w.status == "free":
        return True
    else:
        return False
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
    print(domain+" had an issue")
    return False

def check_available(matches):
    print('checking availability')
    available=[]
    for match in matches:
        if(check_domain(match)):
            print("found "+match+" available!")
            available.append(match)
    return available
```

I've also tried names.com/names bulk upload tool but that doesn't seem to work at all.

How do I determine the availability of these domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example `multiprocessing` package to speed-up the process, i.e.:

```py
import os
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from whois import whois


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391735/10035985
def blockPrint():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")


def enablePrint():
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


def check_domain(domain):
    try:
        blockPrint()
        result = whois(domain)
    except:
        return domain, None
    finally:
        enablePrint()
    return domain, result.status


if __name__ == "__main__":
    domains = [
        "google.com",
        "yahoo.com",
        "facebook.com",
        "xxxnonexistentzzz.domain",
    ] * 100

    results = []
    with Pool(processes=16) as pool:  # <-- select here how many processes do you want
        for domain, status in tqdm(
            pool.imap_unordered(check_domain, domains), total=len(domains)
        ):
            results.append((domain, not bool(status)))

    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["domain", "is_free"])
    print(df.drop_duplicates())
```

Prints:

```
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████| 400/400 [00:07<00:00, 55.67it/s]

                      domain  is_free
0   xxxnonexistentzzz.domain     True
5               facebook.com    False
11                google.com    False
14                 yahoo.com    False
```

You can see it checks ~55 domains per second.

Comment: Nice job! this is running quite fast and should finish in an hour. lets see what it outputs

Comment: @gnarbarian From over 100 years to just one hour, that's like a million times faster. Amazing.